# Sort object keys/entries in specific order

Tags: javascript, sorting

I have an object like this:

```js
const data = {
  val5: 1231,
  val3: 1232,
  val1: 1233,
  val2: 1234,
  val4: 1235,
};
```

And its has to be sorted by it keys but in specific order:

```js
const sortOrder = ["val1", "val3", "val2"];
```

If the key is not present in the `sortOrder` then it has to go below the keys that are present. And the non present keys order should (potentially) stay the same.

The result object should look like this:

```js
{
  val1: 1233, // present in sortOrder at position 0
  val3: 1232, // present in sortOrder at position 1
  val2: 1234, // present in sortOrder at position 2
  val5: 1231, // NOT present in sortOrder
  val4: 1235, // NOT present in sortOrder
}
```

I've been playing with sorting the keys only for now and can achieve some order but the non present keys are appearing at the top

```js
const ordered = Object.keys(data).sort((a, b) => {
  return sortOrder.indexOf(a) - sortOrder.indexOf(b);
});
```

```js
[ 'val5', 'val4', 'val1', 'val3', 'val2' ]
```

As you can see `val5` and `val4` are the beginning and they should be at the end (after `val2`)

Comment: You almost had it, the only issue is that you're not checking if sortOrder actually contains the key you're iterating or not. 

If you do `sortOrder.indexOf(x)` but `x` is not in `sortOrder`, then `indexOf` will return `-1`, explaining why the non-existent keys are always on top (`--1 === +1`). See [reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf#return_value) for more info.

The fix is to add `if (!sortOrder.includes(b)) return -1` before the rest of the evaluation in the sorting function.

Comment: While it is possible to have order for objects (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5525795) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30076219)) I wouldn't recommend it. The ordering is very easy to disturb and might be for any number of reasons. One very notable example would be sending a network request - JSON handling libraries might change to any other order of the properties. Consider using a different data structure if the order of keys matters. A Map might work.

Comment: @lorikku to be honest ive reached to the same conclusion but when add the `includes` part then the result order is a bit odd `[ 'val4', 'val1', 'val3', 'val2', 'val5' ]`. Not sure why `val4` is now at the front.

Comment: @VLAZ at the moment (and it foreseeable future) the source data is a static json and it loaded as it is

Comment: @StefanStoichev maybe try to add: `if (!sortOrder.includes(a)) return 1` as well (also before the actual evaluation).

Comment: @lorikku thats make a lot of sense :) thanks. if you put it as an answer im happy to accept it

Comment: @StefanStoichev How do you accomplish ? Can you please post answer.

Comment: @JaydeepMor for some reason cant post an answer but the whole example is: ```const data = {
  val5: 1231,
  val3: 1232,
  val1: 1233,
  val2: 1234,
  val4: 1235,
};

const sortOrder = ["val1", "val3", "val2"];

const ordered = Object.keys(data).sort((a, b) => {
  if (!sortOrder.includes(b)) return -1;
  if (!sortOrder.includes(a)) return 1;
  return sortOrder.indexOf(a) - sortOrder.indexOf(b);
});
console.log(ordered);
```

Comment: @StefanStoichev Thank you! It's working. [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Jaydeep_Mor/sqj9mrtf/53/)

Comment: @StefanStoichev I'm happy it worked for you, however, I'm not able to put it as an answer because this question was closed by a moderator since it's been 'answered before'. The decision was too impulsive imo, but yeah I'm glad nonetheless that I was able to help you out :)

Comment: @lorikku yea agree that it was to impulsive to close the question. its a different problem to the other questions. I'm trying to re-open it :)

Comment: @lorikku the question is now open and can be answered :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost had it, the only issue is that you're not checking if `sortOrder` actually contains the key you're iterating or not.

If you do `sortOrder.indexOf(x)` but `x` is not in `sortOrder`, then `indexOf` will return **-1**, explaining why the non-existent keys are always on top (--1 === +1). See [reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf#return_value) for more info.

The fix is to **manually** put all keys that are not present in `sortOrder` at the end of the array:

```
if (!sortOrder.includes(a)) return 1 
if (!sortOrder.includes(b)) return -1
```

So in the end, you'd have this:

```
const ordered = Object.keys(data).sort((a, b) => {
  if (!sortOrder.includes(a)) return 1 
  if (!sortOrder.includes(b)) return -1
  return sortOrder.indexOf(a) - sortOrder.indexOf(b);
});
```